# clickablespan change color ACTION_DOWN (onTouch)

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, clickable

I need my ClickableSpan to change the links background when they are touched.
Thats my code:

```
holder.text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    holder.text.setText(addClickablePart(post.getTweet().getText()), BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

int idx1 = str.indexOf("#");
int idx2 = 0;
while (idx1 != -1) {
    idx2 = str.indexOf(" ", idx1);
    if(idx2 == -1) {
        idx2 = str.length();
    }

    final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
    ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
                public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
                    super.updateDrawState(ds);
                }

                @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            if(clickString.startsWith("#")) {
                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "left",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } 
        }
    }, idx1, idx2, 0);
    idx1 = str.indexOf("#", idx2);
}
```

I don't see how I can pull it off...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background xml something like this:
put in you drawable folder
and set in you spinner:

```
android:background="@drawable/YOUR_XML_FILE"
```

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape

     ///WHEN PRESSED TO CODE HERE WILL BE ACTIVATED///

    </shape>
  </item>
<item>
    <shape

     ////YOU CODE FOR WHEN NOT PRESSED///

    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: you put 2 different colors for each state?